# Strange working cycle in C

Tags: c, cycle

```
int n = 0;
int temp = 0;

while ((temp != 1) || (n <= 0)){
  puts("enter array count");
  temp = scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("\n%d\n", temp);
}
```

I need to check input value for the fact it must be an integer and be > 0.

`scanf` returns count of success set values and if it's not an integer it will return 0.

So the problem is that when I'm typing any char except number it starts non-finished cycle

Why?

[image]

Comment: read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf) and note what the return value means.

Comment: so what is my mistake? I see zero result but why cycly starts and executing forever?

Comment: @t0mm13b The OP already knows about the return value.

Comment: I can hardly understand the mistake. ok, how can I fix it?

Comment: you could type in an actual number,  then the loop will exit.

Comment: when you type something other than a number, scanf returns 0 into `temp`.  the top of the loop requires that `temp` be '1' to exit the loop, so the execution stays within the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type something invalid, such as a character, for `scanf("%d", &n);`, the `scanf` fails, returns 0, and **leaves the invalid data in the `stdin`**. In the next iteration `scanf` sees this invalid data prevailing in the `stdin`, fails again and this process is repeated.

The fix is to clear the `stdin` in each iteration of the loop. Add

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

or

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
scanf("%*c");
```

just after the `scanf` to clear the `stdin`.